# Output values from variables into a text file on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

How can I output values from variables from the workspace into a text file on MATLAB.

1)How do I get the output as below? 
[image]

2)I have saved my features as "feature1...feature5"
[image]

3)Here is the output of the feature1
[image]

4)Here is the list of my features (features1..5 can be seen here)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gather all feature variables into one variable and write to an ASCII delimited file.

Code -

```
feature = [feature1 feature2 feature3 feature4 feature5];
dlmwrite('myfile.txt', '', 'delimiter', '');
for c2 = 1:size(feature,1)
    str1=[ num2str(median(feature(c2,:)))];
    for c1 = 1:size(feature,2)
        str1 =[str1 [' feature',num2str(c1),':' num2str(feature(c2,c1))] ];
    end
    dlmwrite('myfile.txt', str1, 'delimiter', '','-append');
end
```

The text file would look like this :

```
1 feature1:1 feature2:1 feature3:1 feature4:0 feature5:1 
0 feature1:0 feature2:1 feature3:0 feature4:1 feature5:-1 
0 feature1:1 feature2:0 feature3:0 feature4:1 feature5:-1 
0 feature1:0 feature2:0 feature3:0 feature4:1 feature5:1 
0 feature1:1 feature2:0 feature3:0 feature4:0 feature5:-1 
1 feature1:1 feature2:0 feature3:1 feature4:1 feature5:1 
0 feature1:0 feature2:0 feature3:0 feature4:1 feature5:-1
```

Please confirm if this is what you need!

Comment: How about the label?
0 feature1:0 feature2:1 feature3:0 feature4:0 feature5:1
I mean the first character "0", when 0 appear the most in those 5 features.

Comment: The first character is the label, which means 0 occur the most in 1st row,
eg:feature1:1 feature2:0 feature3:0 feature4:0 feature5:-1 
"1" occur 1 time, 0 occur 3 times, -1 occur 1 time, then the label will show the most (0) in front.

Comment: For ur second row of output, the label will show "1" as the label because "1" occur the most in second row....

Comment: Had to add MEDIAN for that. Done finally I think!